# How to overload >> operator to take variable argument list

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm looking to overload a '>>' operator such that someone can enter any number of values.

This is the requirement verbatum from the assignment I'm working on:

> Operator>> should expect to see input in the following form: d v1 v2 …
>   vd , where d is the dimensionality of the vector and each vi is the
>   value corresponding to index i in the vector.

The way I assume it would work would be that the first value would be the size of the array (contained in object Vex), and the rest would be elements. So if they were to type in

```
Vex vX;
4, 1, 2, 3, 4 >> vX;
```

vX would create a dynamic array of size 4 containing the numbers 1-4.

The main part I'm hung up on is how to program the >> overload because there will be a variable number of arguments.

Ideally I would have a solution to the effect of... (this is just an example):

```
std::istream& Vex::operator>>(istream& is, const Vex&){
   /*
     Assume int * data has been previously declared in constructor
     data = new int[iterator[0]]
     create iterator of input for istream
     For n from 1 to iterator[0]...
         data[n] = iterator[n] 
   */
}
```

I just don't know exactly how to do that. I've been looking around and I've found istream_iterator, but I can't find any good examples of someone using it in the way I need to use it.

I hope the info I've provided is enough to answer the question. Please let me know if not.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You cannot do that.  There are other ways to do it that would be just as convenient, such as `vX = {1,2,3,4};`, but if you must insist on this particular syntax, you're out of luck.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm being clear, I will copy the requirement from my programming assignment verbatim: "Operator>> should expect to see input in the following form: d v1 v2 … vd , where d is the dimensionality of the vector and each vi is the value corresponding to index i in the vector."

Comment: You should really get clarification from your teacher, but I'm quite certain that `d v1 v2 ... vd` refers to is user input at runtime.  Not source code.

Comment: This is non-idiomatic. >> is the extraction operator but you are using it like an insertion operator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your teacher is not asking you to overload `operator>>` to take a variable argument list.  He's asking you to overload `operator>>` in such a way that it parses variable length input at runtime, given by the user (or a file, or any `istream` object).  The signature you need is this:

```
std::istream& operator>>(istream& is, Vex& v)
```

It should not be a member function, but you may need it to be a friend.

I don't know anything about this `Vex` class, so I can't tell you how to write the function, but it would go something like this:

```
read an integer N from the stream
set size of Vex object as N, however that's done
for i = 1 to N
    read number X from the stream
    store X in Vex object at position i
```

Comment: Do you mean "store X in Vex object at position **i**"?

Answer (score 0):

Your argument list needs to be comma separated, then you can pass several of them in one `operator<<` call.

OpenCV does this. Here is how it is to be used (search for comma-separated):
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=comma-separated#mat

Have a look at their code of `cv::Mat_` here:
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/matx.hpp line 840

It uses an auxiliary object, your task is to find out how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the comma is an operator. It evaluates each expression and returns the value of the right hand operand. Also, it associates from left to right. Finally, `>>` has higher precedence than `,`. This means that

```
4, 1, 2, 3, 4 >> vX;
```

is equivalent to

```
((((4, 1), 2), 3), (4 >> vX));
```

but `4, 1` evaluates to `1`, so the above evaluates to

```
(((1, 2), 3), (4 >> vX));
```

which evaluates to

```
((2, 3), (4 >> vX));
```

which evaluates to

```
(3, (4 >> vX));
```

which evaluates to

```
4 >> vX;
```

So for the above statement to compile, you must overload

```
Vex& operator>>(int, Vex&);
```

From the comment to your original question, it appears that the professor wants you to overload `operator>>` for your `Vex` class. This means that the signature should be:

```
istream& operator>>(istream&, Vex&);
```

Comment: No, `>>` binds more tightly that `,`, whether it's overloaded or not, so `4, 1, 2, 3, 4 >> vX` is equivalent to `4, 1, 2, 3, (4 >> vX)` (which in turn is equivalent to `(4 >> vX)`, since the literals have no side effects and their values are discarded).

Answer (score 0):

You are over thinking it. Read the spec more carefully. I think the following is pretty close to what is being asked.

GCC 4.7.3: g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++0x

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

template <class T>
struct Vex {
  std::vector<T> v;
};

template <class T>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Vex<T>& vex) {
  auto dim = 0;
  is >> dim;
  for (auto i = 0; i < dim; ++i) {
    T t;
    is >> t;
    vex.v.push_back(t);
  }
  return is;
}

int main() {
  std::stringstream is("4 1 2 3 4");
  Vex<int> vex;
  is >> vex;

  for (auto i : vex.v) {
    std::cout << i << " ";
  }

  return 0;
}
```